# Upgrading firmware of an EOS-1Ds with large CF-cards

Tags: canon, firmware, upgrade, compactflash, canon-1ds

In order to get the EOS-1Ds to identify large (greater than 2 GB) CF cards the firmware has to be updated to version 1.0.3. The manual states that a CF card between 8 MB and 2 GB must be used in order to upgrade the firmware of the camera.

Given that CF cards where quite low capacity back in the days, maybe these capacity limits just reflect the available cards at the time. Is it possible to use a larger capacity card while upgrading? Or do I need to get a older card just to perform the upgrade?

Comment: If the current firmware can't understand the larger cards, how could it update the camera to a new firmware *from* a larger card?

Comment: @mattdm Since without the update it only supports FAT16 and the update enables the use of FAT32. It could be possible to format a larger capacity card in FAT16 and only make use of 2 GB and use that card to update the firmware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now successfully upgraded the firmware in my EOS-1Ds using a 8 GB CF card that was formatted in camera to a 2 GB FAT16 partition. The card used was a Trancend CompactFlash 133x 8 GB.